# Image sizes with Asset Catalog and Sizing Classes for a iOS 8 Universal app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, autolayout, ios-universal-app

My app is currently just for iPad, I think I might be able to just make a smaller version of iPhone, with the 'any' sizing class.

EDIT: I just want to use a universal storyboard if possible.

I think I will just need to select iPad and iPhone in my asset catalog image sets.

I'm hoping I can make proportional constraints, however I'm not sure how to do with without providing constant widths / heights for images.

How do I then work out what images I will need to provide, also whats the best way to provide images?

I've seen you can provide vector images, I believe the documentation said that Xcode would produce the sizes required from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Image resources.** Essentially, for universal iOS apps (for the iPhone/iPad/AppleWatch UI idioms and various display scale factors), there is an extensible way - [Asset Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1).

Once you have configured your assets, you can access your image resources as usual (via `UIImage.imageNamed()`) and the system will do the rest for you.

**2. Layout constraints/ size classes.** When dealing with the layout of your image contents, it's no longer a matter of what images you have - it's a matter of how your app's UI adapts to the idiom of the device it's being run on. At least, you can use aspect ratio [layout constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1) to make your image views scale proportionally in accordance with the enclosing layout context (device screen size, parent view size, etc.). Also, it's a good practice to utilize [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html).

P.S. My answer is as vague as the question is. If some of the aforementioned is too broad, please feel free to chat with me on the SO chat. Good luck.

Comment: I'm worried that xcode with resize the images and lose clarity

Comment: Xcode will definitely use pngcrush during the build phase in order to "optimize" your images. Xcode will not resize your images (in terms of dimensions), though. For instance, when assigning an image of incorrect size for the app icon, Xcode will raise at least a warning in order to let you know that a transformation is required.

Comment: What about other image sets ?

Comment: Xcode has no clue what size is required when it sees a custom-purpose asset catalog. Thus, it will not touch anything in terms of width and height. However, UIKit might render your images in an unexpected/unintended way when trying to fit your graphic contents into the according layout conditions.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, so is it best to provide big images and let it resize them down ?

Comment: No way, as it causes CPU rendering which takes much time to be performed. Moreover, you might get some shape distortion effects.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, images are managed with the UIImage class, then can be displayed in a multitude of ways, but mainly with the UIImageView class. The UIImageView class will do all of the resizing required for your image, making it a vector image in itself.

1. This is how you create an image. The image file (imagename.png) is stored in your xcassets.

   ```
   var myImage = UIImage(named: "imagename.png")
   ```
2. This is how you assign an image to an image view programmatically, assuming you have an outlet to the imageView named myImageView.

   ```
   myImageView?.image = myImage
   ```

Comment: sorry I meant to add that I want to use storyboards only. I'll edit the question.